# Javascript for running code-behind code when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have a popup that is getting displayed when Save button is clicked. The popup has 2 buttons. Yes and No. No should cancel the popup
and yes should take you to function in the code-behind say, btnSave_Click(object sender, Eventargs e). How is it possible. Could someone help me, i am new to Javascript.

Below is the code where i am showin the popup.

```
var mdlPopup = $find('<%= ModalPopupExtendersavechanges.ClientID %>');
     if(mdlPopup)
     {
       mdlPopup.show();           
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you will need to set your server side function as a web method like this:

Add to the top of your code behind:

```
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
```

Then decorate your method with these attributes:

```
 [WebMethod(), ScriptMethod()]
 public static void btnSave_Click(Object sender)
 {
   //Stuff
 }
```

To call this from the client side (Javascript) do this:

```
PageMethods.btnSave_Click(this,btnSave_Click_Finished);
```

You can place that in a client click event.  The first argument is the sender parameter, the second is the javascript function to call when the server side method has completed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call server side code from JavaScript directly. Make a postback or fire a XHR (AJAX) request in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible for you to acess the serverside script by using javascript.
`__doPostBack`is a function which is behind the asp postback and this function is called when a button is clicked or dropdown value is changed.
For more details pls refer to [this.][1]

All you need is to place a `<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" onClick="btnSave_Click" />` in the form and in the javascript (ie button click function) just call the `__doPostBack('<%= btnSave.UniqueID %>', '');`

So it will calls the serverside function.(btnSave_Click)
 Notice that you need to give `'<%= btnSave.UniqueID %>'` as the firstargument.

The above will works as similar to a server button click

The another way is to make a post or ajax using [jquery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) it is possible to send request asynchronously to the server.Here you want to pass some query string and call the appropriate function in the `page_Load` 
This will do without any postback

One another method is to use PageMethods from clientside by defining a static [WebMethod](http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.)

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720099%28vs.71%29.aspx/"Call serverside function from clientside"
I hope any one of these will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

the `Yes` button should be an asp.net control with a server-side handler

#### markup

```
<asp:button id="yesButton" runat="server" onclick="yes_click" />
```

#### codebehind

```
void yes_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   // TODO your thing here.
}
```

the other buttons can be standard html `input`s with javascript event handlers. if you are using javascript to alter element style, the changes won't persist across a postback- when the yes button submits and the page reloads, the popup won't be visible.